# Check if multiple variables are empty and set their values bourne shell

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

I have many variables `var1 var2 ... varx` that may or may not be empty. I don't want to have multiple `if` statements and was wondering how to make a loop, to which I supply a list of variables and it checks if they are empty. If a variable is empty, its value should be set to `-`

Comment: What environment?  Bash?

Comment: @bc2946088: Bourne shell

Comment: write this part *a loop, to which I supply a list of variables* at start. Then, we could help you with the rest

Comment: Having variables like `var1`, `var2` and so on is not a good idea. Use an array instead

Comment: How many is *many*?  Is the amount statically set?

Comment: @hek2mgl : I don't think Bourne shell can do arrays, but its been years since I had to use it. O.P. I'm almost sure that even Bourne shell supports parameter evaluation/assignment like `: ${var1:=Var1Value} .... ` Good luck.

Comment: Bourne? **Really**? Note that `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh (a specification published in 1991), not Bourne (a specific codebase from the 1970s), on all modern platforms.

Comment: @Mr.SrJenea, ...btw, are the names *really* suffixed with numbers, or was that just for purposes of example?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: just for purposes of the example

Comment: @hek2mgl You should post that as an answer; IMO a long list of `: ${var1:=-}` statements is going to be more useful than a `for` loop for determining which variables are set.

Comment: @chepner I totally agree with that. I don't see how a loop makes things simpler or more readable here. (or brings any benefit at all) Just go ahead and post it. I'd appreciate that. (I'm kind of busy atm). Besides that, I just see a very few use cases where it makes sense to name a variable like `name_1`, `name_2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This puts you into `eval` territory:

```
for var in var1 var2 varx; do
  eval 'val=$'"$var"
  if [ -z "$val" ]; then
    eval "${var}=-"
  fi
done
```

Note that any source that can provide arbitrary variable names can abuse this to run arbitrary code; ensure that you only use it in scenarios, like the above, where the values for `var` are under your control.

Answer (score 1):

As @hek2mgl first mentioned, you can assign a default value to a variable if it does not already have a value with

```
: ${var1:=--}
: ${var2:=--}
: ${var3:=--}
# etc
```

Note that this takes more space than a loop would, but it is more readable, as it doesn't require any indirection to decipher.

Comment: Good answer! :) Btw, can you read thoughts? I was actually not saying that, but thinking it. Especially since the `${var:-default}` syntax is POSIX compatible, which seems to matter here.. I think it was @shelter who was saying that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating an array `arr`, instead of having multiple variables ,iterating over the elements of the array and replacing empty ones with `--`

```
for element in "${!arr[@]}"; do
   out[$element]=${out[$element]:---}
 done
```

Comment: Arrays aren't supported in Bourne *or* POSIX sh. If this works, your shell is clearly something much more modern.

Answer (score 0):

Bash allows you to do recursive substitution of variable names, so you can use things like `${var${suffix}}`, but `sh(1)` doesn't, so you have to use `eval` expressions to allow for deferred variable expansion, like in:

```
#!/bin/sh

TEMPFILE="/tmp/defaults.sh-$$"
trap 'rm -f "$TEMPFILE"' 1 2 3 15

# FORMAT IS FIRST WORD IS VARIABLE NAME, REST OF LINE IF DEFAULT VALUE.
cat > "$TEMPFILE" << EOF
A default value for variable A
B default value for variable B
C default value for variable C
PATH /bin:/usr/bin
HOME $HOME
EOF

while read name value
do
    eval echo "$name==\$$name"
    if 
        [ -z "`eval echo \\\$$name`" ]
    then
        echo "$name=\"$value\""
        eval "$name=\"$value\""
    fi
done <"$TEMPFILE"

while read name dumb
do
    eval echo "[$name] =\> \$$name"
done >&2 <"$TEMPFILE"
rm -f "$TEMPFILE"
```

I've used a temporary file, as I make two passes through it (I did this for debugging purposes) but if you don't need the second pass, just do

```
#!/bin/sh

while read name value
do
    eval echo "$name==\$$name"
    if 
        [ -z "`eval echo \\\$$name`" ]
    then
        echo "$name=\"$value\""
        eval "$name=\"$value\""
    fi
done <<EOF
A default value for variable A
B default value for variable B
C default value for variable C
PATH /bin:/usr/bin
HOME $HOME
EOF
```

So, finally, without traces, you get something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read name value
do
    if [ -z "`eval echo \\\$$name`" ]
    then
        eval "$name=\"$value\""
    fi
done <<EOF
A default value for variable A
B default value for variable B
C default value for variable C
PATH /bin:/usr/bin
HOME $HOME
ANOTHER_VARIABLE default value for ANOTHER_VARIABLE.
EOF
```

## NOTE

I have tested this against GNU Bash and FreeBSD Bourne Shell.  The golden test should be to test it against AT&T V7 bourne shell, but I don't have one at hand to make the tests.  My apologies for that (but working on it!) :)